# Invoke Pipeline in account B from lambda in account A

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, devops, identity-management

I want to invoke a codepipeline in account B from account A using Aws Lambda and also want to send CommitId and some other information like lifecycle etc which i want to use in that codepipeline.

I have tried to create IAM roles and create trust releationship between them but getting erros

Comment: What is the "pipeline" you mention? Given that you mention "Commit Id", are you referring to CodeCommit? Feel free to Edit your question with more details, so that readers can better understand what you are wanting to do.